# Facebook custom story is published without action-type and object

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, tags, facebook-stream-story, custom-stories

My custom story did not pass Facebook review and since then when i'm trying to publish my custom story, it is published without the action-type (found) and the object (a thing), just the user message and the URL. 
further more, all my published story had been changed, the action-type and the object disappeared from them.

In my "find" action type i'm using "Tags" & "User message" capabilities.

Here is my post request:

```
 $.post("https://graph.facebook.com/me/MYAPP:MY_ACTION?"
                + "access_token="+USER_ACCESS_TOKEN
                + "&MY_OBJECT=OBJECT_URL
                + "&message="+ USER_MESSAGE
                + "&privacy={'value':'EVERYONE'}"
```

Does anyone familiar with this issue?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using?